# How to add search control on leaflet map using Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet, esri-leaflet

I am using [leaflet.js](https://leafletjs.com/) with [ngx-leaflet](https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet) and [esri-leaflet-geocoder](https://github.com/Esri/esri-leaflet-geocoder) packages.

I am able to using search box on the leaflet map with plain JavaScript. All I need is the following line:

```
var searchControl = L.esri.Geocoding.geosearch().addTo(mymap);
```

But I am unable to accomplish this in Angular. I tried the following:

```
layers = [];
searchControl = Geocoding.geosearch();
this.layers.push(this.searchControl); // in the constructor
```

HTML:

```
<div style="height: 300px;"
     leaflet
     [leafletOptions]="options"
     [leafletLayersControl]="layersControl"
     [leafletLayers]="layers"
     [leafletFitBounds]="this.polygon.getBounds()"
     (leafletClick)="mapClicked($event)">
</div>
```

I am getting the error which says:

> ERROR Error: "The provided object is not a Layer."

I consoled `searchControl` and the result is same for both plain JavaScript and Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround not sure if it's a best solution.

Import CSS of the plugin:

```
import 'style-loader!esri-leaflet-geocoder/dist/esri-leaflet-geocoder.css';
```

Pass the map object when the map is ready:

```
<div style="height: 300px;"
     leaflet
     [leafletOptions]="options"
     [leafletLayersControl]="layersControl"
     [leafletLayers]="layers"
     [leafletFitBounds]="polygon.getBounds()"
     (leafletClick)="mapClicked($event)"
     (leafletMapReady)="onMapReady($event)">>
</div>
```

And add controller to the map same like plain JavaScript:

```
onMapReady(map: L.Map) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    map.invalidateSize(true);
    this.searchControl.addTo(map);
  }, 0);
}
```